# Multiple string search in txt file (java)

Tags: java, loops, comparison, readline

```
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(id_zastavky), "windows-1250")
);  

for (int i = 0; i < id_linky_list.size(); i++) 
{
    while ((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         String pom = id_linky_list.get(i);                     
         String[] result = sCurrentLine2.split("\\|");
         if((result[1].toString()).equals(pom.toString()))
         {
            System.out.println(result[1].toString()+"   " +pom.toString() + "  " + result[3]);
         }
      }
}
br2.close();
```

Hey guys. Anyone can give me advice why is my FOR loop using only first item in my id_linky_list a then it quits? I think that the problem is on this line

> while ((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null)

. I have over 5 000 items in my list and I need to compare them if they exist in my txt file. If I run my App the for loop only takes first item. How should I modify my code to make it work properly? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

during the first iteration of for loop, the whole file will be read and `br2.readLine()` will always return null for next iterations.

Instead of that if the file size is small you could build a map and you can use that map to check the content

```
    File file = new File("filename");
    List<String> lines = Files.linesOf(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
    Map<String, List<String>> map = lines.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line -> line.split("\\|")[1]));
    List<String> id_linky_list = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < id_linky_list.size(); i++) {
        if (map.get(id_linky_list.get(i)) != null) {
            //sysout
        }
    }
```

**Update**

```
Map<String, List<String>> text = Files.lines(file.toPath(), Charset.forName("windows-1250")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line -> line.split("\\|")[1]));
```

Comment: `Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file.toPath(), Charset.from("windows-1250"));` instead of `linesOf` or `readAllLines`.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you, I imported wrong `Files` from someother package,  updated answer

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone can give me advice why is my FOR loop using only first item in
>   my id_linky_list a then it quits?

Simply because you read your entire file in the loop `while ((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null)` when you first call it which is when `i = 0` next calls will do nothing as the file content has already been read so `br2.readLine()` will return `null`.

> How should I modify my code to make it work properly?

You need to invert the loops `for` and `while` as next

```
while ((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < id_linky_list.size(); i++)  
    {
```

---

To get better performances consider using a `Set` instead of a `List` to store your words and simply check if a given word exists by using the method [`contains(object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) instead of iterating over your `List`.